# Parse.com : Query Max Value of Column in JS API

Tags: javascript, api, parse-platform

If in sql, we can get it with:

```
select Max(Column_name) from Table_name
```

but still can't find simple way to get Max value of Column in Parse.com JS API.

Please explain me how to get Max Value of Column in JS API?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to use [Parse.Query (api)](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html) and order by [descending](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html#descending), then obtain the [first](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html#first) item in the result.

**Edit:**
Maybe, it's not a good idea to use `order by` in the situation that there are thousands(or even more) items as it's time consuming(complexity at least **O(nlogn)**). An alternative is to write a function of your own to choose the maximum value yourself with complexity of **O(n)**.

Comment: Thank you... i found this way from parse.com help. but it was 1 year ago. i hope i got the simpler way.

Comment: @AhmadDani See the edit. You can choose the suitable way according to your application.

Answer (score 2):

Write a query for descending order and fetch the first object out of it. You will have the max value of the column there.

```
 var query = new Parse.Query("something");
 query.descending("column_name");
 query.first({
       success: function(result){
       var max = result.get("column_name");
       },
       error: function(){
       },

 })
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you can do it directly with a max function. You can create your own max function by doing a query to get all entries from that column and sorting them in descending order. There are APIs for this. Then choose the first value from the sorted list.

Comment: Thank you..this max value of Column will placed at other parse.Query as value of greaterThan other Column. May you give me sample max function to do that ? Thank you..

Answer (score -1):

You can basically follow the same pattern from all other queries:

```js
// Query for ID
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Table_Name");
// Condition
query.orderByDescending("ID");
// First object will be retrieved, this will be the max_value
query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
if (object == null) {
   Log.d("score", "The getFirst request failed.");
} else {
   Log.d("score", "Retrieved the object.");
}
```

Now you can get the value using something like:

```js
String mensagem = object.getString("ID");
```

Hopefully this will help you!